# How I make a trigger for add in a field of a table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

**I want to make a trigger on MYSQL that increases the value in the field of a table**

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Lollipop;
CREATE DATABASE Lollipop;
USE Lollipop;

/* Sucursales */ 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sucursales;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sucursales (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Direccion VARCHAR(50),
    Numero_empleados DECIMAL(10) DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

/* Empleados */ 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Empleados;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Empleados (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombres VARCHAR(25),
    Tipo_de_sangre VARCHAR(3),
    Seguro_social VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    Fecha_nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    ID_Sucursal INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TRIGGER add_empleados
BEFORE INSERT ON Empleados
UPDATE Sucursales
SET Numero_empleados = Numero_empleados + 1
WHERE id = new.ID_Sucursal;
```

*When I try to insert the trigger it sends me an "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax"*

Comment: As far as I know, `FOR EACH ROW` is not optional. [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: And there is no `ID_Sucursal` in `Empleados`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `FOR EACH` ID not optional

`CREATE TRIGGER add_empleados BEFORE INSERT ON Empleados UPDATE Sucursales SET
FOR EACH Numero_empleados = Numero_empleados + 1 WHERE id = new.ID_Sucursal;`